# Access the link inside div with same structure

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Below is the HTML Structure of my code, which is mostly same structure with only difference is alignment. I just want to access the  link element inside particular div.

I tried using the index property to select and access the div. But it's not working. Is there any idea, on how to use index properly?

```
<div class="connections-table">

            <div class="connection-row layout-align-space-between-center layout-row" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

              <div flex="40" class="flex-40"></div>

              <div flex="20" class="title text-center flex-20">Specialty</div>

              <div flex="20" class="title text-center flex-20">Geography</div>

              <div flex="20" class="title text-center flex-20">Total</div>

            </div>

            <div class="connection-row layout-align-space-between-center layout-row" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

              <div flex="40" class="label flex-40">Medical School</div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, 'medschool_specialty')" class="ng-binding">3</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, provider.metrics.medschool_geo.label)" class="ng-binding">2</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, 'medschool_total')" class="ng-binding">79</a></div>

            </div>

            <div class="connection-row layout-align-space-between-center layout-row" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

              <div flex="40" class="label flex-40">Residency</div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, 'residency_specialty')" class="ng-binding">19</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, provider.metrics.residency_geo.label)" class="ng-binding">0</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, 'residency_total')" class="ng-binding">104</a></div>

            </div>

            <div class="connection-row layout-align-space-between-center layout-row" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

              <div flex="40" class="label flex-40">Clients Nearby</div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, provider.metrics.clients_nearby_specialty_geo.label)" class="ng-binding">3</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, provider.metrics.clients_nearby_geo.label)" class="ng-binding">112</a></div>

              <div flex="20" class="text-center flex-20"><a ng-click="list(provider.npi, provider.metrics.clients_nearby_geo.label)" class="ng-binding">112</a></div>

            </div>

          </div>
```

How to automate this is Selenium?

Comment: You tried to use `index property`, but it doesn't work, so you want to use `index property`... hmm...interesting :) Show code you've tried and specify exact element you want to handle

Comment: it seems that you are using an angular js application. I suggest you to use protractor instead of plain selenium

Answer (score 0):

As I see the links are different, so the best way is to use the unique value from the ng-click attribute.

Example:

```
a[ng-click*='part of uniques attr value']

a[ng-click*='medschool_geo']
```

Or if you need indexes then use the `nth-of-type()` for the elements on the same level.

Example:

```
.connections-table div:nth-of-type(2) div:nth-of-type(3) a
```

I recommend using the first example by `ng-click` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of xpath in Selenium for uniquely selecting the desired link inside **div**. Following are some example xpaths that can be used:

```
//div[text()='Medical School']/following-sibling::div/a[contains(@ng-click, 'medschool_total')]

//div[text()='Residency']/following-sibling::div/a[contains(@ng-click, 'residency_total')]
```

If you just want to use the index/predicate, you can use following xpaths. However, this approach may not be reliable, especially when the ordering of **div** may change in future.

```
//div[text()='Medical School']/following-sibling::div[3]/a
//div[text()='Residency']/following-sibling::div[3]/a
```

Please let me know, if I have misinterpreted your question.